# I am facing an error when storing an array in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, userdefaults

> Thread 1: "Attempt to insert non-property list object (\n
> "VPQuizzy.UserDetails(name: \"Wewewe\", userName:
> \"Wefrfrferf\", password: \"wedwedwedwed\")"\n) for key
> userDataList"

```
struct UserDetails{
    let Name:String
    let userName:String
    let password:String
}

 var userList = [UserDetails]()
 
 
  func setUserData(name:String?,userName:String?,password:String?){
        guard let name = name,let userName = userName,let password = password else{
            print("Please check again the code")
            return
        }
        if let storedUserList = UserData.dictionary(forKey: UserDefaultKey.userDataList.rawValue) as? [UserDetails]{
                    userList = storedUserList
                } else {
                    userList = []
                }
        userList.append(UserDetails(Name: name, userName: userName, password: password))
        print(userList)
        setUserData(userList)
    }
    func setUserData(_ userList:[UserDetails]){
        UserData.setValue(userList, forKey: UserDefaultKey.userDataList.rawValue)
    }
```

Comment: UserDefaults is not reliable storage for storing passwords. You need use keychain.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think the error is caused by using `array`.

> A default object **must be a property list**—that is, an instance of (or for collections, a combination of instances of) NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, **NSArray, or NSDictionary**. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

(emphasis mine)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Besides the recommendation, you might consider using an `NSArray` (to be honest, I don't know what the tradeoffs are, so that becomes another topic).